# Multinomial probit regression with mixed type explanatory variables

Tags: r, glm

I have a data frame called `aggregates` composed of numerical columns each having a significant amount of zero values. I want to fit a probit model for each column by regressing them on another data frame called `exp_vars`. `exp_vars` is composed of factors, ordered factors, integers and numbers. I tried this:

```
probit_reg = lapply(aggregates, function(y) glm(y ~ subset(exp_vars, select=-c(HH_Net_Income)) + log(exp_vars$HH_Net_Income) + 
log(exp_vars$HH_Net_Income)^2 + log(exp_vars$HH_Net_Income)^3 , data = cbind(y = y, exp_vars)))
```

But I got this error:

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

I know that the error is not related to the formula I set, because even with the most basic formula I get the same error:

```
probit_reg=lapply(aggregates, function(y) glm(y ~ exp_vars, data = cbind(y = y, exp_vars)))
```

I feel like this has something to do with the fact that some of my predictors are factors, but I don't know why it should be a problem and how to fix it. Should I create binary variables for each level of all my factors or is there an easier why to use factor predictors with glm?

Here is a reproducible example:

```
    aggregates <- data.frame(agg1 =c(1,0,0,0,0), agg2=c(1,1,1,0,1))
    exp_vars <- data.frame(exp1 =c(21:25), exp2=c(11,12,21,22,23), exp3=c(1,0,0,1,1))
    exp_vars$exp2 = ordered(exp_vars$exp2, levels = c('11','12','21','22','23'))
    exp_vars$exp3 = as.factor(exp_vars$exp3)

     agg1 agg2
#1    1    1
#2    0    1
#3    0    1
#4    0    0
#5    0    1

# exp1 exp2 exp3
#1   21   11    1
#2   22   12    0
#3   23   21    0
#4   24   22    1
#5   25   23    1

probit_reg=lapply(aggregates , function(y) glm(y ~ exp_vars ,family = binomial(link = "probit"), data = cbind(y = y, exp_vars)))

#Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ exp_vars , data = cbind(y = y, exp_vars ),  : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'exp_vars '
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is indeed about the formula. The following works

```
lapply(aggregates , function(y) glm(y ~ . ,family = binomial(link = "probit"), data = cbind(y = y, exp_vars)))
```

The issue is that when you write `y ~ exp_vars`, `glm` looks for a variable named `exp_vars` and finds a data frame, which it doesn't like. Writing

```
data = cbind(y = y, exp_vars)
```

doesn't mean that all the columns of `exp_vars` can be referred to as `exp_vars`. In fact,

```
cbind(y = 1:5, exp_vars)
#   y exp1 exp2 exp3
# 1 1   21   11    1
# 2 2   22   12    0
# 3 3   23   21    0
# 4 4   24   22    1
# 5 5   25   23    1
```

Meanwhile, writing `y ~ .` means that regress `y` on everything else that you find in `data`, which is what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. This would have been the ideal solution if I wanted to regress y linearly on every variable in exp_vars. But ideally, I want to regress it on every variable in exp_vars except for income plus the log of income to the power of 1,2 and 3. The issue with this is that there are many other variables in exp_vars, so i don't want to write them one by one. Is there anyway to deal with this problem?

Comment: @ElifCansuAkoğuz, yes, if I understood you correctly, you may then write your formula as `y ~ . -inc + log(inc) + I(log(inc)^2) + I(log(inc)^3)`. It takes out `inc`, but adds those other three terms.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what i need! I am sorry, i am quite new to nonlinear regression in R, it didn't occur to me to write it that way.

Comment: @ElifCansuAkoğuz, no problem, I'm glad to help. Other than this `I(...)`, I guess the only other things used in formulas are `:` (interaction) and `*` (interaction and individual terms).